# Pandas dataframe conditional mean

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to find the average number of cigarettes smoked per day among women who smoked during pregnancy for a given dataset. Currently, I'm trying

```
mean = data.groupby(['male', 'cigs']).mean()
print(mean)
```

That gives me the mean average family income for each amount of cigarettes smoked per day (ie 0 per day, 2 per day, 8 per day, ect). How do I get it so it's the average family income for those who smoked >= 1?

Also, this is my first post on stack so forgive me if there isn't enough detail.

Comment: If you are trying to filter results based on an groupby aggregation you can use the filter method.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html

Comment: A few things when you ask a question on stackoverflow. #1. Provide sample data so people can understand what you are referring to. #2. Provide sample output so people can relate to the end result. #3. sample code that shows what you have tried. It is difficult to figure out what you are saying without seeing some data and desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I assume "*cigs*" refers to number of Cigarettes smoked per day. You can first filter the data based on cigs >=1 and then apply what you were doing.

```
data_on_people_who_smoke = data[data.cigs >= 1]
mean = data_on_people_who_smoke.groupby(['male', 'cigs']).mean()
print(mean)
```

Comment: This still gives the mean based on the number of cigs. To get the mean of all observations of cigs >= 1, simply remove 'cigs' in the groupby.. However, it still splits the mean income based on gender

Answer (score 0):

```
mean = data[data['cigs']>1]['income'].mean()
print (mean)
```

This gives you the mean of the income of all respondents that smoke at least 1 cig. don't groupby gender or cigs. Filter first, and get the mean.